# Eval Date to show just day number

Tags: c#, .net, eval

I am using the following code

```
Eval("EventDate", "{0:d}")
```

This returns 1/4/2011

I need it to return "4" just the day. But if I do this

```
Eval("EventDate", "{0: d}")
```

It returns " 4" note the space, this is causing problems is there anyway to just get the day number without that space.

Thanks

Comment: Try this: String.Format("{0:d}", Eval("EventDate"));

Comment: Have you tried this ? `Eval("EventDate", "{0:dd}")`

Comment: ditto - what is `Eval`?? i get what it (probably) does, but which lib is this from?? (or is it a custom static function that uses some sort of reflection)

Comment: @Oded @jim http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hx47hfe.aspx

Comment: atrljoe - thanks, not using .net 4 yet, so hadn't come across that. thanks..

Comment: OK - I was missing the asp.net context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this using `Eval("EventDate", "{0:%d}")`. The `%` indicates that this is a custom format string.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```
String.Format("{0: d}", Eval("EventDate")).Replace(" ", "")
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, `d` here is synonym for a short date pattern (`DateTimeFormatInfo.ShortDatePattern` - `M/d/yyyy` for en-US culture).

You could use

```
Eval("EventDate", "{0: dd}")
```

which gets you `04` or

```
((DateTime)Eval("EventDate")).Date
```

or just

```
string.Format("{0: d}", Eval("EventDate"))
```

as proposed above.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head I would try adding a Trim on the end of the Eval statement.  Like this:

Eval("EventDate", "{0: d}").Trim()